# Using KDE libraries on Qt

Tags: qt, kde-plasma

I am relatively new to Qt (by relatively new I mean I have developed a few basic applications on Qt). I wanted to work on KDE Games using Qt and came across things like `kapplication.h`, `KMainWindow`, etc. How do I use these on Qt and how are these different from the corresponding `QApplication` or `QMainWindow` in Qt?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that these header files are for the KDE development libraries, without knowing too much about working with these libraries I think it would be reasonable to assume that they are used to better integrate your program into a KDE desktop. If you were to write a program using these headers then you'd have to include KDE runtime libraries if you wanted to use that program on a GTK environment like Gnome or XFCE. This adds unnecessary dependencies to your program when you could just use straight Qt libraries in lieu of the KDE libraries. Unless your program is explicitly intended to run on KDE then I would advise using Qt. But if you wanted to tailor your application to a KDE environment then the KDE libraries would be a good choice.

In short, if you're targeting Windows, Gnome, XFCE, Cinnamon, KDE etc... then Qt. If KDE is your choice solely, then use these headers. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is IDE, that uses KDE with qt, KDevelop, you can look at it here: http://www.kdevelop.org/